# How can I display a block as a node?

Tags: nodes, routes, blocks

I've got a modules that supplies a bunch of blocks. I'd like to be able to display them individually as stand-alone pages. I can embed them into nodes, but then I'll need to create each node manually. Ideally I'd just create a menu entry specifying which specific block I'd like to display.

Is there anything out there that can do that? I'm looking for basically the inverse of http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by [Empty Page](http://drupal.org/project/empty_page) module

> The Empty Page module is a simple empty page solution. It provides an
>   interface that assists in managing "empty" menu callbacks, mostly used
>   for pages that only consist of blocks

Please your block in separate [Empty Page](http://drupal.org/project/empty_page)'s

Answer (score 0):

I would do this from my custom module. I would create a men path and a page callback which renders the block.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['my/block/path'] = array(
        'title' => 'Block As A Page',
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_block_as_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );  
    return $items;
} 
/**
 * Page callback the path for my/block/path
 */ 
function mymodule_block_as_page(){  
    $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'module_delta');
    return $block['content'];
}
```

If you go to the path **my/block/path**, you will see your block as a page/node.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with hook_menu

Provide a generic menu handler for viewing a block at `block/view/module_name/delta`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 * Provides block view page at:
 * /block/module_name/delta
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    // Pass generic module_name and delta as args
    $items['block/view/%/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Block page',
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_block_page',
        'page arguments' => array(2,3),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );  
    return $items;
} 
/**
 * Page callback the path for block/module/delta
 */ 
function mymodule_block_page($module, $delta){ 
  if (module_exists($module) && !empty($delta)) { 
    $block = module_invoke($module, 'block_view', $delta);
    return isset($block['content']) ? $block['content'] : MENU_NOT_FOUND;
  }else{
    return MENU_NOT_FOUND;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

Comment: I made a conscious decision not to use Panels for this particular site (nothing wrong with Panels, Omega/Delta was a better fit). @Sithu, David, hook_menu is the direction I was thinking originally, and may end up doing a "proper" custom module with my Feature once I see how the blocks are working out in practice.